# Spring Rest Doc not producing html

Tags: java, spring, api-doc, spring-restdocs

I followed the [getting started guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#getting-started) for Spring Rest Doc word by word, but I cannot get any html out of the generated snippets.

The snippets are generated fine in the directory I configure (*build/generated-snippets*), but I can't see any html5/ directory with html files generated out of the snippets.

The doc [at some point](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-gradle-packaging-the-documentation) says what to do to package the documentation in the jar, and it's clear that it expects some files in an html5/ directory, but this is not created when the build runs:

```
dependsOn asciidoctor
from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
    into 'static/docs'
}
```

What am I missing?

My project files, **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.asciidoctor.convert' version '1.5.2'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext { 
    snippetsDir = file('build/generated-snippets')
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:1.3.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:1.1.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.5'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:1.1.0.RELEASE'   
    testCompile 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-core:1.1.0.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.3.5.RELEASE'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.6.201602180812"
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}

test {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}

asciidoctor { 
    attributes 'snippets': snippetsDir 
    inputs.dir snippetsDir 
    dependsOn test 
}

war {
    dependsOn asciidoctor
    from("${asciidoctor.outputDir}/html5") {
        into 'static/docs'
    }

    baseName = project_name
    version = version
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Implementation-Title': project_name,
            'Implementation-Version': version
        )
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.13'
}
```

and a simple test file I use to test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ApiDocumentation
{
    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("build/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception
    {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(document("index"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a hand-written `.adoc` file that is including the generated snippets? Also, how are you running your build? You need to run the `asciidoctor` task to produce the HTML from the `.adoc` file(s) and snippets.

Comment: I don't have an hand-written adoc. I thought I needed one but I am not sure where to put this in order to be picked up? The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#getting-started-using-the-snippets) is a bit unclear on this. After digging in the asciiidoc gradle plugin code I tried to change [what the documentation says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-gradle) at point 4 (changed inputs.dir to sourceDir) and I can see html files now in build/asciidoc/html, is this a doc mistake?

Comment: No, it's not a mistake. Setting the generated snippets directory as an output of the test task and an input of the asciidoctor task allows Gradle to figure out task dependencies and perform accurate up-to-date checks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create an .adoc file (like api-guide.adoc) under `src/main/asciidoc` (Maven) or `src/docs/asciidoc` (Gradle) with reference to the generated snippets . Then the html will be generated in the specified directory .

Comment: If I do that, still no html is produced. If I change the `build.gradle` file in the asciidoctor section (inputs.dir changed to sourceDir) I can see some html produced from the generated snippets in `build/asciidoc/html`, but not the one for the `api-guide.adoc` I just created in `src/main/asciidoc`.

Comment: The Asciidoctor Gradle plugin looks in `src/docs/asciidoc` by default so that's where your hand-written `.adoc` file should go.

Comment: I have the same problem. The .adoc document in the right place but still no html.

Comment: what means 'generated in the specified directory'? Where is it specified? It ain't the 'src/main/asciidocs' folder, is it?

Comment: @DirkSchumacher by specified directory he means `build/asciidoc/html5`. I am assuming you have followed the documentation as it is.

Answer (score 0):

use: `{spring-restdocs.version}` in place of `{project-version}`
then update project.

It'll look something like this,

```
dependencies {
    asciidoctor 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-asciidoctor:{spring-restdocs.version}' 
    testCompile 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc:{spring-restdocs.version}' 
}
```

After that,
Project > right-click > maven > update-project.

Then re-build the project. hope this will solve your problem.